# Is this conclusion logically valid?

Tags: logic

Premise 1: No home cooked food is good

Premise 2: No good food is wasted

Conclusion: No home cooked food is wasted.

Not sure if this is logically valid or not and why? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- **Premise 1**: No home cooked food is good.
- **Premise 2**: No good food is wasted.
- **Your conclusion**: No home cooked food is wasted.

There are three possibilities given the two premises. Graphically through Venn-diagrams:

[image: First possibility]
[image: Second possibility]
[image: Third possibility]

Your conclusion isn't necessarily false, as the top Venn-diagram shows, but it does not logically follow, as the bottom 2 Venn-diagrams show.

Answer (score 2):

The conclusion doesn't follow from the premises. Note that doesn't necessarily imply that the conclusion is false.

It would logically follow if you had written it this way:

```
Premise 1: ALL home cooked food is good.
Premise 2: No good food is wasted.
Conclusion: No home cooked food is wasted.
```

In this way, if the two premises are true, the conclusion *must* be true. With your example, the conclusion could be either true or false (i.e. even though No home cooked food is good, they still might not waste it [the bad food]).